# multiple lookup powershell array

Tags: arrays, powershell

have an array with organization data
like this:

```
org_id  org_name        parent_id
1       Company         NULL        
2       HR              1           
3       MARKETING       2           
4       FINANCE         1           
5       IT              4
```

So the structure is:

```
[Company]
|- HR
| |- MARKETING
|- FINANCE
| |- IT
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can query which parent organization an organization has for a specific user.

So if a user has defined that they belong to IT I want to match string in org_name and get parent_id. then match parent_id against org_id so in the end get org_name, in this case FINANCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, your organization array is like this:

```
$Company = [PsCustomObject]@{ org_id = 1; org_name = 'Company'; parent_id = $null },
           [PsCustomObject]@{ org_id = 2; org_name = 'HR'; parent_id = 1 },
           [PsCustomObject]@{ org_id = 3; org_name = 'MARKETING'; parent_id = 2 },
           [PsCustomObject]@{ org_id = 4; org_name = 'FINANCE'; parent_id = 1 },
           [PsCustomObject]@{ org_id = 5; org_name = 'IT'; parent_id = 4 }
```

With this you can do

```
$department = 'IT'
$parentId   = ($Company | Where-Object { $_.org_name -eq $department}).parent_id
$orgName    = ($Company | Where-Object {$_.org_id -eq $parentId }).org_name
```

After this, `$orgName` contains `FINANCE`

If the department you are after is `HR` or `FINANCE`, it will return `Company`
If you search for department `MARKETING`, you'll end up with `HR`
etc.

Comment: Thanks! this work just fine. started doing some while loops to find a specific row and then match that row index with the parent id row. this is much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this [Join-Object](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet (see also: [what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848821/1701026)), you might make use of it's self-join feature to create a cross reference:

```
$List = ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
    org_id  org_name        parent_id
    1       Company         NULL
    2       HR              1
    3       MARKETING       2
    4       FINANCE         1
    5       IT              4' # https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable

$Reference = FullJoin $List parent_id -eq org_id '', 'parent'
$Reference | Format-Table # Show what's in the $Reference

org_id org_name  parent_id parentorg_id parentorg_name parentparent_id
------ --------  --------- ------------ -------------- ---------------
1      Company   NULL
2      HR        1         1            Company        NULL
3      MARKETING 2         2            HR             1
4      FINANCE   1         1            Company        NULL
5      IT        4         4            FINANCE        1
                           3            MARKETING      2
                           5            IT             4
```

Selecting a parent organization of an organization:

```
$Organization = 'IT'
($Reference | Where-Object org_name -eq $Organization).parentorg_name
FINANCE
```

Or vice versa: selecting the organization(s) of a parent organization:

```
$Parent = 'Company'
($Reference | Where-Object parentorg_name -eq $Parent).org_name
HR
FINANCE
```